# Accessing variable names of Javascript arrays

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have the following javascript array:

```
[["0", Object { name="john"}], ["1", Object { surname="white"}]];
```

How can i print the variable name "name" (not "john", which is its value)

```
console.log(result[0][1] ?????);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data[0][1]` returns `{name: "john"}`. You can then use the `Object.keys` function that will return the keys of an object. It will return `['name']`. Then you just have to get the first item of this array.

```js
const data = [["0", {name: "john"}], ["1", {surname: "white"}]];

console.log(Object.keys(data[0][1])[0]);
console.log(Object.keys(data[1][1])[0]);
```